# 1 route stops working when I create another route PHP Lravel

Tags: laravel

I am running into an issue where I do not get any error message. I have created a controller where user can Add/edit their profile details. The route for this is:

```
Route::post('/profilecompany',[CompanyProfileController::class,'store']);
```

The controller function to store the profile details is:

```
public function store(Request $request){                  
   CompanyProfile::create($request->all());       
   return redirect('/profilecompany')->with('success','Profile updated Successfully');
}
```

It works fine. But then I created option to upload file on the same page. The web route is :

```
Route::post('/profilecompany',[CompanyProfileController::class,'upload']);
```

And the controller function to upload is:

```
public function upload(Request $request){        
    $request->validate([
        'document' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,pdf,doc,docx|max:5120'
    ]);
    $filename = $request->user()->id;
    $request->file('document')->store('public/userdocs/'.$filename);              
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'File uploaded');
}
```

Individually, it works fine too. Now the issue is, when I have both routes together in my web.php file, the first function stops working. Which means when I try to add profile details, it does not get saved in the database and, strangely, I also do not see any errors. So I am not sure why the two routes do not work together.

Comment: You can't have both occupy the same route and also same HTTP method. Why not something like `/profilecompany/documents` for the upload?

Answer (score 1):

You just overide first route by make another one with same url and same http method

To fix it you can simply make urls make more detailed like:

```
Route::post('/profilecompany/store',[CompanyProfileController::class,'store']);

Route::post('/profilecompany/upload',[CompanyProfileController::class,'upload']);
```

And don't forget to change url of request in your ajax/axios/http request or whatever u use to connect frontend withbackend